# Rails css changes not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, macos

I'm learning to develop a web app using Rails on mac osx. I just added some css styling to my webpage. But every time I edit it and save it, and run `rails s` I cannot see the changes I made in the CSS on my webpage. I tried doing a hard refresh using `COMMAND+SHIFT+R` as well, but no luck. Any one know what's going on? I'm using firefox by the way.

Comment: Doers the CSS that you're changing live in .css files or in the .html.erb files? That could make a big difference in the final answer...

Comment: Which version of rails?  If it's 3.1+ you'll need to rake assets:precompile also

Comment: @BobGilmore the scripts are in .css files.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I'm sing 3.1.0. Could please explain a bit more how I need to take assets:precompile?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the css is being cached by the the web server. In your view, you need to add an autogenerated timestamp at the end of the css file name like so:

```
app.css?t=12044402444
```

or disable caching in your web server of choice.